# How to clear air vents of leaves and other such debris?

Tags: hvac, cleaning

Car is a civic vti 99. It was left under a tree for some 8 months or so.

Recently started to use it and smelt bad. Cowel screen and under it was covered in leaves and pollen and the the cabin filter(located under glove box) was absolutely filthy. Changed the cabin filter and it did improve the situation

significantly.  However on using heating etc I noticed leaves coming out of the air vents.

i'm assuming there are leaves and debris throughout the entire hvac system forwhatever reason e.g improperly installed cabin filter.

1. Since pollen and leaves cannot really get past a cabin filter and I have now changed it, I guess I dont really have to remove and clean any parts of the hvac that occur before the cabin filter e.g. cowel screen or blower motor? I can just replace the filter more often and so not cleaning these wouldn't cause leaves or pollen smells etc in cabin vents.  Is this a safe assumption?
2. What parts of the system then occur after the filter that I should remove and clean?  I looked at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS26Em2Pdtk but it has no sound so I cannot knwo the part names.  I can see two units after the filter, what are they called, do I typically need to remove and clean them all out, or in the case of 95-2000 civics, what parts will I need to move and clean?
3. how much time would this job typically take a mechanic, is it small medium or big?

Comment: Leaves etc won't go past a filter unless it was damaged or badly fitted. It will take as long as it takes, if the system needs such thorough cleaning then it will take time.

Comment: I would assume this is perhaps one of the largest jobs one can do. I mean, the air channels are behind the dashboard. It won't be easy to clean them!

Comment: @juhist Is it not just a case of removing the dashboard and heating unit then manually cleaning it all out?  similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04MlTepEIz4 ,however in my car the cabin filter seems to be after the blower motor so perhaps I don't need to clean pre cabin filter items. I guess its one of the biggest jobs excluding engine work such as replacement or rebuild.