# How might a cabin filter be damaged or improperly installed?

Tags: cabin-filter, cabin

Recently had leaves coming out of my air vents after I replaced a cabin filter so I imagine the old filter was damaged over time or I made a mistake during installation.  The fitler is behind the glove box and sits horizontally.  It seems to have been a simple task, take old one out and slide new one in.

However after removing the old I did try to vacuum some leaves out of he housing as well as use a brush to brush some parts out.  Might the vacuuming/brushing have caused leaves to flow into the vents by accident?
The sidea of the filters seem to have dirt/leaves on them but not the back so I'm wondering if due to age the edges wore out and the leaves slid through the edges of the filter?

Would the above be good reasons why the leaves got through, what other mistakes might one make during a cabin filter installation which leads to leaves in the cabin vents?

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/69415/10976

Comment: @SolarMike I edited the original question as there were too many question in one.  That is asking about removing leaves from vents whereas this about cabin filter installation.